# preg_match_all, espressão regular no php com variaveis

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Olá estou com dificuldades em monta a expressão regular, e a função me retorna 3 posições no array todas vazias;

```
preg_match_all('/<a data-role\="sku\" data-sku-id\="'.$the_new_id[2].'\" id\="sku\-3\-'.$the_new_id[2].'\" href\="javascript:void(0)\">(.*)<\a>/i', $page_content, $sku_3_a);

array(3) {
[0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  array(0) {
  }
```

Comment: Qual a *string* que você está utilizando? Quais partes da *string* você quer capturar?

Comment: O valor de dentro da tag <a>: <a data-role="sku" data-sku-id="201301155" id="sku-3-201301155" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>32cm</span></a>

Comment: parece que contou pela quantidade de itens que está no site, mas não retornou o conteúdo.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente não está funcionando pois você está escapando as aspas sem necessidade. Você só precisa escapar essas aspas, quando a função começar com elas, por exemplo

```
preg_match_all("necessário \" escapar", $var)
```

Caso contrário

```
preg_match_all(' "Aqui" não precisa ', $var)
```

---

Caso você esteja tentando extrair os links de uma página, basta usar a “Regex” abaixo (mais curta):

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*data-sku-id="'.$dataSkuId.'".*id="sku-\d-'.$yourId.'"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/i', $page_content, $sku_3_a);
```

Caso você queira pegar apenas o valor do HTML, basta usar `strip_tags`

```
strip_tags('<a data-role="sku" data-sku-id="201301155" id="sku-3-201301155" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>32cm</span></a>');

// Output: 32cm
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo exemplo, estou testando